# passing variables to an attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

How can I pass a variable in jquery like this:

```
   var info = $(this).attr("id");
   var course2 = $('div[name=info]').html;
   $("#courseinfo").html(course2);
```

I am having difficulty with the second line..

Comment: What is the relevance of `info`?  Are you expecting to find a div with that value on the 2nd line?

Comment: you are passing info as a string, so u need to pass it as a variable using '+'

Comment: 1) -> line 1 info is getting the id attribute. Line 2 is using info as the name to use in the second variable. 2) Yes, I needed to use +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var info = $(this).attr("id");
var course2 = $('div[name="' + info + '"]').html();
$("#courseinfo").html(course2);
```

- Put `info` variable inside quotes.
- Get the html part of the `div` using the `html()` method without any arguments.
- Set the html for the `courseinfo` by passing the html string like `html(course2)`.
- For more details, please read [`.html() API Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I wasn't sure about concatenation in jquery, very helpful.

Comment: @LindsayW It's fine but please do read the API Documentation carefully before working on any new jQuery event, methods, etc. You can get all the details here: [**jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var course2 = $('div[name="'+info+'"]').html();
  $("#courseinfo").html(course2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var course2 = $('div[name="'+info+'"]').html();
```